# In JavaScript, is there a way of parsing JSON that turns numbers into strings?

Tags: javascript, json, floating-point

As JavaScript uses floating point maths for all numbers, which does not preserve precision in all cases, I want to parse a JSON object containing numbers but generate strings in the returned JavaScript object rather than number objects. Is there a way to do this using standard or third party libraries?

Comment: I really doubt that any commonly-available library would do that. You'd be better off generating the JSON with numbers as strings in the first place.

Comment: As you suggest, "I want to parse...". I think you need to manipulate the JSON _string_ and make the numeric values strings, before importing - perhaps with a regexp?

Comment: @w3d manipulating the string is possible, but because there may be strings of digits already embedded in strings it might be almost as hard as just parsing the JSON directly.  The source for JavaScript JSON parsers is available and it'd be pretty easy to modify, I suspect, since the parser has to collect the numeric constants in string form anyway.

Comment: FYI... PHP's [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function allows you to do just this when the optional 4th argument is set to `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. This may not be a perfect solution (especially the reg expression), but hope it will help you to solve this.

```
var json = '{"num1":123.89075576575775676575, "num2":89.5564764646476444844, "num3":56.4353454354353535435435435}';

json = json.replace(/\d+.\d+/g, function(a, b){ 
    return '\"' + a + '\"';
});

console.log($.parseJSON(json )); // I have used jQuery. Any JSON parser can be used
```

Comment: This will also escape numbers within strings, unfortunately.

Comment: That you can avoid by modifying the reg expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regexp, something like:

```
 var numstrings = JSON.parse(json.replace(/\:([0-9.]+)(,?)/g,':\"$1\"$2'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmwcZ/

Comment: If he calls `JSON.parse`, then the numbers in the JSON representation that can't be represented accurately in JavaScript will be broken before your function can be called.

Comment: Right, made an example using regexp instead.

Comment: This will also escape numbers within strings, unfortunately.